# 2D Wall Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I followed a tutorial about implementing a wall jump but one thing that doesn't work is getting the character pushed on the opposite side of the wall when pressing the jump button. As it is, character is only jumping on the y axis upwards on the wall. I just started coding so any help is appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling, stagger }

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MovementState currentState;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator anim;
    public FloatValue currentHealth;
    public SignalSender playerHealthSignal;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableWall;
    

    private  float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float WallSlideForce;
    
    private bool isWallSliding;
    private float wallSlidingSpeed = 2f;

    private bool isWallJumping;
    private float wallJumpingDirection = 0;
    private float wallJumpingTime = 0.2f;
    private float wallJumpingCounter;
    private float wallJumpingDuration = 0.4f;
    private Vector2 wallJumpingPower = new Vector2(8f, 16f);

    [SerializeField] private Transform wallCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;

    public float attackDamage = 20;

    public float attackRate = 2f;
    float nextAttackTime = 0f;


    [SerializeField] private Transform _center;
    [SerializeField] private float _knockbackVel = 8f;
    [SerializeField] private float _knockbackTime = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private bool _knockbacked;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
                Debug.Log("Hello World!");
                rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
                sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    { 
        if(!_knockbacked) //knockback und Damage
        {
            dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            currentState = MovementState.idle;
        }
        else
        {
            var lerpedXVelocity = Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0f, Time.deltaTime * 3);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(lerpedXVelocity, rb.velocity.y);
            currentState = MovementState.stagger;
        }
        
        
      
      if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")  && IsGrounded())
        {
          rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }

      if(Time.time >= nextAttackTime)
      {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
         {
             attack();
             nextAttackTime = Time.time + 1f/attackRate;
         }
      }
      
      

      UpdateAnimationUpdate();
      WallSlide();
      WallJump();
       
     }

    private bool IsWalled()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(wallCheck.position, 0.4f, wallLayer);
    }

    private void WallSlide()
    {
        if (IsWalled() && !IsGrounded())
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("WallSlide");
            isWallSliding = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -wallSlidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("WallSlideOf");
            isWallSliding = false;
        }
    }

    private void WallJump()
    {
        if (isWallSliding)
        {
            isWallJumping = false;
            wallJumpingDirection = -transform.localScale.x;
            wallJumpingCounter = wallJumpingTime;

            CancelInvoke(nameof(StopWallJumping));
        }
        else
        {
            wallJumpingCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && wallJumpingCounter > 0f)
        {
            isWallJumping = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(wallJumpingDirection * wallJumpingPower.x, wallJumpingPower.y);
            wallJumpingCounter = 0f;
           
            Invoke(nameof(StopWallJumping), wallJumpingDuration);
        }
    }

    private void StopWallJumping()
    {
        isWallJumping = false;
    }

     void attack()
     {
         if (sprite.flipX == false)
         {
             anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
         }
         else if (sprite.flipX == true)
         {
             anim.SetTrigger("AttackLeft");
         }
         
     }

     private void UpdateAnimationUpdate()
     {
         MovementState state;

         if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
     
     }

     private bool IsGrounded()
     {
         return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
     }
     

     public void Knockback(Transform t, float damage)
     {
         currentHealth.RuntimeValue -= damage;
         playerHealthSignal.Raise();
         if (currentHealth.RuntimeValue > 0)
         { 
             anim.SetTrigger("Hit");
             var dir = _center.transform.position - t.position;
             _knockbacked = true;
             rb.velocity = (Vector2)(dir.normalized * _knockbackVel);
             StartCoroutine(routine:Unknockback());
         }
         else
         {
             this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
                
     }

     private IEnumerator Unknockback()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(_knockbackTime);
         _knockbacked = false;
     }
}
```